# C# creating an array in a singelton class

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, singleton

I want to create an array of Disc which id like to include fields string[] Record, int NumberHeads and string extension. so basically grouping them and instantiate the array once and only once as i dont want more than one of this array in the memory. How can i do this as my fields dont seem to be under the array Disc and if i make them public and run the application i get a null reference exception.

I was initially using a struct but I came to realise these cannot be passed from class to class in C#.

```
class DiscType
{
    private static DiscType[] disc;
    private static string[];
    public bool discSelect;
    public int maxRecord;
    public int numberHeads;
    public string extension;

    public static string[] Record
    {
        get
        {
            if (record == null)
            {
                record = new string[1000];
            }
            return record;
        }
    }

    public static DiscType[] Disc
    {
        get
        {
            if (disc == null)
            {
               disc = new DiscType[10];

            }
            return disc;
        }
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DiscType.Disc.Length; i++)
        {
            DiscType.Disc[i].Record[i]= "1";
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you populate some data, `DiscType.Disc[i]` will remain `null`! Are you initializing the `Array` in `InitializeComponent()` ?

Comment: You can skip the `if (disc == null)` if You `private static DiscType[] disc = new DiscType[10]`

Comment: `record` doesn't exist

Comment: `private static string[];` doesn't mean anything... Please, provide real code

Comment: You might want to consider using the [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class for doing lazy initialization.

Comment: Not your solution, but I would just like to dispel the myth that you cannot pass structs from object to object. You either misunderstood or got bad information on that point.

Comment: Can you pass them between classes ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only once instanciation of your array do it like that :

```
   public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;
   public string[] MyArray { get; set; }
   //better using a List<string>

   private Singleton() {
      //instanciate MyArray here
   }

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

After that you just need to call it like that :

```
Singleton.intance.MyArray
```

Comment: It's true. He could look at this link if he want to do it thread safe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: Thank you for all your answers will try some of the suggestions

Comment: How do instantiate myArray?

Answer (score 0):

You describe two problems:

- After you think you created a DiscType and an array of records, your array of records only contains null values
- Your DiscType is not a singleton.

**Is Disctype a singleton?**

Someone else already described how to create a Singleton, So I wont write this. However I doubt whether DiscType in your design really is a singleton. If you'd describe your design in words, would you talk about **the one and only disctype**, or would you say: "Although in my designed world it could be that there were several different disctypes, however because of the huge amount of memory and mabye because of the time it takes to create one, it is advised to use only one disctype during the session".

In the latter case, you should not design it as a singleton. The famous gang of four wrote in their book about design patterns (where the singleton is described) as one of the major rules of design:

> Design for change

That means, that you should not restrict your design merely for the case that in the current usage it is not needed. If in your current configuration you only need one disctype, just create only one. If in future versions you need two, you don't need to change your disctype.

So careful review your design: are we talking about "the one and only disctype"? or are we only restricting to one because we don't have enough memory?

**Why is my array of records empty**

To understand this, you need to know the difference between value types and reference types. Simple types and structs are value types. They exist as soon as you declare them. Instances of classes are always reference types: you need to call new ... to create them. If you don't do this, the value is null.

```
Myclass X;
string text;
int i;
System.Drawing.Point p;   // a Point is a struct!
```

- X and text both have a null value, the only thing you can do with them before you assign something to them is compare them with null
- i and p already have a value. You can get them and call their methods.

**Back to your problem**

Your code:

```
public static string[] Record
{
    get
    {
        if (record == null)
        {
            record = new string[1000];
        }
        return record;
    }
}
```

You assign a newly created object to record. the object is an array of strings, which are reference types. You haven't assigned anything to each string, so each string in your array is still null, and you can't do anything with them until you assign something.

The array of strings however is initialized. You can use methods of the array. You can ask for the length of the array. You can also ask for item[3] in which you get the uninitialized (null) string.

**List instead of Array**
By the way, this method of initializing is a bit unusual. I guess you don't want to reserve memory for records as long as you don't use them. You would have accomplished that by using List.

My advise is to familiarize yourself with class List. It will make your life so much easier. Before long you'll feel the desire to know all collection classes :-)